# how to prevent one sql table to be affected when updating another table

Tags: mysql

```
String update_sql = "UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET FIRST_NAME=?, LAST_NAME=?,     EMAIL=?, PHONE_NUMBER=?, HIRE_DATE=?, JOB_ID=?, MANAGER_ID=?, DEPARTMENT_ID=? WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID=?";
                        PreparedStatement ps_one = connection.prepareStatement(update_sql);
                        ps_one.setString(1, FirstName);
                        ps_one.setString(2, LastName);
                        ps_one.setString(3, Email_final);
                        ps_one.setString(4, PhoneNumber);
                        ps_one.setDate(5,sqlDate);
                        ps_one.setString(6, Job);
                        ps_one.setInt(7, Manager_final);
                        ps_one.setInt(8, Department_final);
                        ps_one.setInt(9, id_final);
                        ps_one.executeUpdate();
```

here is my code. i try to update one table and another table was affected.

```
ORA-02290: check constraint (GAS.JHIST_DATE_INTERVAL) violated
ORA-06512: at "GAS.ADD_JOB_HISTORY", line 10
ORA-06512: at "GAS.UPDATE_JOB_HISTORY", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'GAS.UPDATE_JOB_HISTORY'
```

i got that error from another table.

Comment: There's a trigger defined for any update ops on Employees table. Check why `GAS.UPDATE_JOB_HISTORY` is required and failing. Without a trigger, updates done to one table don't affect another table. Updates may still fail because they don't satisfy a constraint depending on some other table but they can't update some other table without a trigger defined that explicitly does so.

Comment: UPDATE_JOB_HISTORY AFTER EACH ROW GAS UPDATE ENABLED EMPLOYEES

that is the trigger found

Comment: TRIGGER "GAS".update_job_history
  AFTER UPDATE OF job_id, department_id ON employees
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  add_job_history(:old.employee_id, :old.hire_date, sysdate,
                  :old.job_id, :old.department_id);
END;

here is the code for trigger